# Где хранить логику в redux приложениях?

Tags: redux

Есть список товаров, он хранится в store приложения. Когда пользователь кликает на кнопку "добавить", то товар попадает в корзину. Есть несколько способов положить товар в корзину - из карточки товара, из каталога, из самой корзины (увеличить количество, уменьшить или удалить вообще).

А где хранить проверку на то, что клиент добавляет корректное количество товара, например, что он не ввел отрицательное число или большее, чем есть на балансе в магазине?

Думаю, что reducer не очень подходит для этих целей, ведь надо как-то клиенту сообщать, что введено не верное количество. А существует несколько видов компонентов для этого действия (кнопки, поля вводя, ползунки и т.п.). К тому же middlware отправляет еще и запросы на сервер.

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-business-logic

Comment: То есть находить свой баланс между редьюсерами и экшн криейторами (или там сагами и прочим). Единого универсально верного ответа нет, это всегда поиск равнвоесия.

Comment: Есть еще вариант - поскольку react-redux приложения все же служат целью замены MVC, то есть слоя презентационного, то логику там хранить вообще нельзя, а выносить ее в отдельный слой.

Comment: ну чувствительная бизнес-логика должна быть на бекэнде конечно. Хотя бы потому что все на клиенте доступно для модификации злоумышленнику. Это не "еще один вариант", у вас всегда есть бекэнд логика отдельно, фронтэнд логика отдельно, и говоря о реакт-редакс мы по умолчанию говорим о фронте.